Configure an automatic redirect in nginx to bypass a missing file
After installing Pi-Hole on an existing system with nginx and Baïkal (a CalDAV server), I cannot make the Pi-Hole admin interface work, there is always a 403 Forbidden error. Pi-Hole works well otherwise. I did not install lighttpd with Pi-Hole, preferring nginx.
Using strace, I found that nginx is failing after looking for several files that are absent. The files should be in /var/www/html/admin/ : index.html, index.htm and index.nginx-debian.html. The only similar file I have is index.php .
This page https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/yesterdays-update-removed-the-index-html/60531/2 says that index.html was deliberately removed and: "You should have a automatic redirect when you access the web interface via pi.hole."
I cannot find anything helpful for this problem. How do I configure an automatic redirect in nginx?
Here is my nginx configuration file, taken from https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/webserver/nginx/ :
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name $hostname;
    autoindex on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
    index pihole/index.php index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        expires max;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param FQDN true;
#        auth_basic "Restricted"; # For Basic Auth
#        auth_basic_user_file /etc/ssl/.htpasswd; # For Basic Auth, same as Baikal
    }

    location /*.js {
        index pihole/index.js;
#        auth_basic "Restricted"; # For Basic Auth
#        auth_basic_user_file /etc/ssl/.htpasswd; # For Basic Auth, same as Baikal
    }

    location /admin {
# Trying to get admin to work, try redirect
        rewrite ^/index.htm$ /index.php permanent ;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
#     index index.php;
#     auth_basic "Restricted"; # For Basic Auth
#     auth_basic_user_file /etc/ssl/.htpasswd; # For Basic Auth, same as Baikal
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
} 

Things I have tried
• autoindex off or on 
• Changing the index directive to just index.php
• auth_basic active and removed
• Adding a rewrite statement

None of these made any difference.
One complication is that both Pi-Hole and Baïkal have a client called ‘admin’. I set both passwords the same, then removed the Pi-Hole password and finally removed the authentication (in Pi-Hole), all with no success.
There should be no conflicts between Pi-Hole and Baïkal. Baïkal listens on port 9999 and Pi-Hole uses 80.
System details
Raspberry Pi 3B with Pi OS bookworm, nginx and Baïkal, all new versions.
Linux Mint desktop with Firefox.

I have been trying different things and it is now working. I'm not sure what caused the success.
I moved some lines to the top of the configuration file. The top is now:
server {
    server_name $hostname;
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;
#    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
    rewrite ^/index.html$ /index.php permanent ;

#    index pihole/index.php index.php index.html index.htm;
#    index index.php;
#    autoindex off;

The critical change seemed be using the hostname in the URL (it's in /etc/hosts on the client). These URLs work:

http://$myhostname/admin
http://$myhostname/admin/queries.php

but not if the IP address is used.
It works without authentication and with basic authentication.
